# Шифрование текста в php и расшифровка на Java

Tags: php, java

Каким образом можно зашифровать текст на php и в дальнейшем расшифровать его на java?

Comment: Java или JavaScript?

Comment: Думается мне, JS :)
Но дал оба варианта

Comment: Именно Java)

Answer (score 4):

Используйте любой распространенный алгоритм шифрования.
Java: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/block_modes.shtml
PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php
Javascript: https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/

Answer (score 3):

Эм, вопрос странный. Метод шифрования и дешифрования будет одинаков, также как md5() даст один и тот же результат как в php, так и в mysql.
Язык здесь не играет особой роли.

Вам просто нужен алгоритм шифрования и дешифрования, и перенести их на выбранные языки